# VS Code : Link and file path not recognized

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

My links and file paths are not recognized (not underlined) in the HTML when my file is in .php . However, when the file is in .html, everything works correctly.
(I need my file to be in .php because I incorporate php in the HTML)

I hope that the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEIYL.png) will allow you to understand my small problem

The problem causes bugs, with CSS in particularly.

Thanks in advance

I already have the Intellisense PHP extension and I'm sure the file paths are correct since it works with the .html file

Comment: Makes sense; PHP is not HTML, just like putting the string literal `<a href="somelink">label</a>` in a JS file isn't HTML. Everything in a PHP file outside of php tags is just "literal text", it's not HTML until a browser gets it _along with_ a header that says it's to be interpreted as the `text/html` mimetype. You can use PHP to generate JS, or CSS, or markdown, or LaTeX, etc. etc. so a parser would have to be _incredibly_ well written to know what's outside your PHP tags (or, have a config file where you can say what it needs to do)

Comment: 1) URLs should use forward slashes (`/`), vs. not DOS/Windows backslashes.  2) Whether or not your IDE happens to display an underline or not does *NOT* "cause bugs", with CSS or otherwise.  It's a *DISPLAY* issue with the IDE - nothing more!

Answer (score -1):

I finally got it to run by clearing the browser cache.